# Babel angry, many bbl errors

Tags: babel, babel-greek

I'm sorry for the vague description, but I don't have much clue what exactly is going wrong.

I would like to include Greek in a LaTeX document. I'm not ready/able/willing/knowledgeable enough to switch to teTeX or LuaTeX now, so I try doing the following perhaps unprepossessing thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\textgreek{αὐλός} 
\end{document}
```

This does not meet with success:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.74 \bbl@trace
               {Compatibility with language.def}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

[...]

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

[...]

```
l.74 \bbl@trace{C
                 ompatibility with language.def}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.101 \bbl@trace
                {Basic macros}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

[...]

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.281 \bbl@trace
                {Hooks}
```

[...]

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.307 \bbl@trace
                {Defining babelensure}
```

[...]

The rest of the logfile is a lot more content of this general shape and I assume it won't help to include it. I get the impression I need to somehow reinstall Babel or hack the related class file to fix this, but I lack the knowledge to do so. I originally installed Babel about a month ago via `sudo apt install texlive-full` on this computer, a new one running Ubuntu 20.04. I tried reinstalling, but it just says I'm up to date.

My TeX version info seems to be

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

Log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.12.17)  10 JAN 2022 11:36
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**aulos_min.tex
(./aulos_min.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
(/home/jeff/Desktop/Dropbox/texmf/tex/latex/jeffplusfixes/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package
 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2020/02/14 3.40 Babel switching mechanism
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf
Language: greek 2016/09/07 v1.9h Greek support for the babel system
 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/02/14 3.40 Babel common definitions
 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2020/02/14 3.40 Babel switching mechanism
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.74 \bbl@trace
               {Compatibility with language.def}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: your document runs without error in an up to date system. you appear to have a broken babel installation with some files expecting a newer babel than you have. installing via apt should have given you something sensible but you may have caught a bad day, you could try updating texlive via apt first

Comment: `kpathsea version 6.3.1` is not relevant for anything. More important is the first line of the `.log`. The example compiles fine for me on TL2021. Have you tried deleting aux files and try again

Comment: show the full log that you get for that test file

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant version info. I just copied but didn't realize I needed to go to a new line after backticks, so the first line was eaten. This is fixed now. The full log file is here: <https://pastebin.com/z2BQpM27>. I am not sure what you mean about updating texlive via apt exactly. I'm at the level of being able to follow basic instructions without knowing precisely what they mean.

Comment: You are loading a core babel code from 2016 !!! then a greek language file from 2020 which not unreasonably is written assuming a 2020 babel.

Comment: I see. Oh dear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log file shows that you are not using the standard babel release but a local version

```
/home/jeff/Desktop/Dropbox/texmf/tex/latex/jeffplusfixes/babel.sty
```

That version is clearly incompatible with the tex system you are using (and using modified versions of standard files is best avoided even when they do not error)

Comment: Thank you! I had no memory of making that local copy and no idea why I did, but I also didn't know a local copy would be prefered in favor of the main installation. I deleted that old version and now things are fine. Thanks again for your help!